Finding the irreducible elements of a polynomial ring
Let $R = \{f(X)\in \mathbb{Q}[X] \space | \space f(0)\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. I am asked to find the irreducible elements of $R$.
I have found that the units in $R$ are $\pm 1$.
If $\deg f = 0$, i.e. $f$ is an integer:
If $f$ were composite, say $f=mn$ where $m,n\neq \pm 1$, then we have the factorisation $f = (m)(n)$ where $m,n$ are both non-units. So $f$ is not irreducible.
If $f$ is prime, say $f=p$ for a prime $p>1$, then we have one (positive) factorisation, namely $f = (p)(1)$. So we have that $p$ is irreducible. Multiplication by a unit preserves irreducibility, from which we conclude $\pm p$ for $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ a prime, are irreducible elements of $R$.
I am unsure how to approach the case of $\deg f \geq 1$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Claim : The irreducible elements in $R$ are of the form $\frac{g(x)}{d}$ where $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible and $d \mid g(0)$.
Proof : For a polynomial $f(x) \in R$, let $d_f := \min\{ r > 0 \mid rf \in \mathbb{Z}[x]\}$.
sub-claim: $f$ is irreducible in $R$ if and only if $d_f f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. To see this, if $f$ is irreducible, then suppose $d_f f = f_1 f_2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $d_f f(0) = f_1(0) f_2(0)$ and hence we can find a factorization $d = d_1d_2$ such that $\frac{f_1(0)}{d_1},\frac{f_2(0)}{d_2} \in \mathbb{Z}$. It follows that we get a factorization of $f$ in $R$, which is $f = \frac{f_1}{d_1}\frac{f_2}{d_2}$ which contradicts irreduciblity of $f$ in $R$. Conversely if $d_f f$ is irreducbile in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and suppose we have a factorization of $f$ in $R$ given by $f = f_1f_2$, then observe we have $d_f = d_{f_1}d_{f_2}$ and hence $(d_f f) = (d_{f_1}f_1)(d_{f_2}f_2)$ a factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which is a contradiction.
Now to complete the proof of the original claim, let $d_f f = g$, then $d_f \mid g(0)$ and $f = \frac{g}{d_f}$ as claimed.
